# Retaining Wordpress classes in html markup (nav_walker)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using a walker class to give my nav menu the structure I want, but I want to retain the existing WordPress classes as well. Even though I am using the concatenate append operator (`.=`) for the `$output`, the WordPress classes are being completely replaced. Any ideas on how this can be rectified? Thanks

```php
class Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker_Nav_menu
{

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = [], $id = 0)
    {

        $postid = url_to_postid($item->url);
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($postid);

        if (array_search('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes) && $depth == 0) {

            $output .= sprintf("\n<li class='topnavitem %s'><a href='%s' class=\"topnavtext\">%s</a> <span class='plus'><i class='fas fa-angle-down'></i></span>\n", (array_search('current-menu-item', $item->classes) || array_search('current-page-parent', $item->classes)) ? '' : '', $item->url, $item->title);
        } elseif (array_search('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes) && $depth == 1) {
            $output .= sprintf("\n<li class='productsnav %s'><a href='%s' class=\"productsnavtext\">%s</a><span class ='sub-plus'><i class ='fas fa-angle-down'></i></span>\n", (array_search('current-menu-item', $item->classes) || array_search('current-page-parent', $item->classes)) ? '' : '', $item->url, $item->title);
        } elseif ($depth == 2) {
            $output .= sprintf("\n<li class='scooppooopnavitem %s'><div class='pictext'><img src='%s'/><a href='%s' class=\"scooppoooopnavtext\">%s</a></div>\n", (array_search('current-menu-item', $item->classes)) ? '' : '', $thumbnail, $item->url, $item->title);
        } else {
            $output .= sprintf("\n<li class='topnavitem %s'><a href='%s' class=\"topnavtext\">%s</a>\n", (array_search('current-menu-item', $item->classes)) ? '' : '', $item->url, $item->title);
        }
    }

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth)
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        if ($depth == 0) {
            $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"nav-level-one\" role=\"submenu\">\n";
        }

        if ($depth == 1) {
            $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"nav-level-two\" role=\"subsubmenu\">\n";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to actually use `$item->classes`, probably just implode it with a space and put it into the `<li>`.

Comment: Is this sample code that you've just removed the results from for posting on this site? If not, both result expressions are the same so it should be refactored out. `(array_search('current-menu-item', $item->classes) || array_search('current-page-parent', $item->classes)) ? '' : ''`